How to prevent PHP from adding default namespace prefixes when importing a sub-XML into another XML
I'm working with PHP 8.2 and need to import an XML node from one document to another without PHP automatically adding the "default" namespace prefix. This is breaking the digital signature in the XML.
Simplified Example:
I have the following XML ($xmlA):
<A xmlns="">
    <B xmlns="">
        <C>Value</C>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
        </Signature>
    </B>
</A>

And I want to import the <B> node into this other XML ($xmlX):
<X xmlns="">
    <Y>Value</Y>
</X>

When I use DOMDocument and appendChild or insertBefore to import the <B> node from $xmlA to $xmlX, PHP adds a default namespace prefix to the <Signature> node, which I don't want:
$xmlA = <<<XML
<A xmlns="">
    <B xmlns="">
        <C>Value</C>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
        </Signature>
    </B>
</A>
XML;

$xmlX = <<<XML
<X xmlns="">
    <Y>Value</Y>
</X>
XML;

$domA = new DOMDocument();
$domA->loadXML($xmlA);

$domX = new DOMDocument();
$domX->loadXML($xmlX);

$nodeB = $domA->getElementsByTagName('B')->item(0);
$nodeB = $domX->importNode($nodeB, true);

var_dump($nodeB->getElementsByTagName('Signature')->item(0)->prefix); //string(0) ""

$domX->documentElement->appendChild($nodeB);

var_dump($nodeB->getElementsByTagName('Signature')->item(0)->prefix); //string(7) "default"

$domX->save('out.xml');

The result (copied as is) is:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<X xmlns="">
    <Y>Value</Y>
<B xmlns="" xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <C>Value</C>
        <default:Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <default:SignatureValue>...</default:SignatureValue>
        </default:Signature>
    </B></X>

What I Need:
I want the resulting XML to maintain the original structure and namespaces without any additional prefixes (indentation is not necessary):
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<X xmlns="">
    <Y>Value</Y>
    <B xmlns="">
        <C>Value</C>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
        </Signature>
    </B>
</X>

Question:
How can I import the <B> node from $xmlA to $xmlX in PHP without PHP automatically adding namespace prefixes or altering the XML structure?
I’m working with DOMDocument and SimpleXML, but PHP keeps adding unwanted namespace prefixes when importing XML nodes, which breaks the digital signature in my case. I've looked through several related questions on Stack Overflow and tried various approaches, but none have resolved the issue.
Is there a reliable way to do this in PHP without manipulating the output as a string to remove the added prefix? Alternatively, I know I could start working consistently with prefixes, but most of the sub-XMLs I need to import come without them, and I need to maintain this format.
Postscript: I had to replace the namespaces of A and B with empty strings so that StackOverflow would let me submit the question, but it works the same.

Why do you care?  What you want and what you have are equivalent.  XML prefixes names can be anything as long as the URI is the same.

The reason I care is that the sub-XML  is digitally signed, and it’s validated by another system that expects the exact structure as it was originally signed. When PHP adds a prefix, it changes the content, and the other system has no way of knowing that it was signed without the "default" prefix, so the signature validation fails.

You are editing the file.  You need a new signature.  Where are you modifying the signature.  The other system does not need default.  It uses the URI (not the namespace default) to validate the signature.

There are other XML stacks available, like SaxonC 12 HE (current version is 12.5) (https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml) where you can use XSLT 3 e.g.
$xmlA = <<<XML
<A xmlns="">
    <B xmlns="">
        <C>Value</C>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
        </Signature>
    </B>
</A>
XML;

$xmlX = <<<XML
<X xmlns="">
    <Y>Value</Y>
</X>
XML;

$xsltCode1 = <<<XML
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

<xsl:param name="doc2"/>

<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="\$doc2/descendant::B[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
XML;

$saxonProc = new Saxon\SaxonProcessor();

$xsltProc = $saxonProc->newXslt30Processor();

$xsltExecutable = $xsltProc->compileFromString($xsltCode1);

$xsltExecutable->setParameter('{}doc2', $saxonProc->parseXmlFromString($xmlA));

$resultDoc = $xsltExecutable->transformToValue($saxonProc->parseXmlFromString($xmlX));

echo $resultDoc;

unset($xsltProc);
unset($xsltExecutable);
unset($resultDoc);
unset($saxonProc);

Result is e.g.
<X>
   <Y>Value</Y>
   <B>
      <C>Value</C>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
      </Signature>
   </B>
</X>

Note that the superfluous xmlns="" are not preserved in XML/XSLT parsing/processing/serialization.
